# Can a Product follows two Product Description template in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to give two button on Product Listing page, one for Add to Cart and Second for customize the product. Now when the customer click on Add to Cart it should go to product description page. If he click on customize button then it should go to other page where he can make changes in product design(can customize t-shirt etc.). I have created the both phtml file for both pages.Now i want that page control go to correct page(depending on click).I have set the phtml file for a category products.But how set two phtml file for product description page for a single category.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear, but in case I understood correctly, you can add a parameter in the url depending on what information you want to show. Let's call it 'show' (a simple 1|0 flag should do).
And in the product view page add something like this:

```
<?php if (Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('show')) : ?>
    //display some content
<?php else : ?>
    //display other content
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need an other template. You can just create 2 different blocks with 2 different names and display one of them, depending on the case. Or if you insist, you can try something like `$this->getChild('child_name_here')->setTemplate('alternative/template.phtml')` before calling `echo $this->getChildHtml('child_name_here')`

Comment: I have created the two template. Now i have to call $this->getChild('child_name_here')->setTemplate('alternative/template.phtml') this code after clicking a button.

Comment: You can call this inside the if statement in my answer. Change the template depending on a var sent through GET

Comment: I do not find any GET in side view.phtml

Comment: read my answer carefully. Send a parameter to the product page through GET (product.phtml?show=1) then make use of that parameter to change the template of a block in the product `view.phtml` file or display one block or another.

Comment: How to set Parameter, Code is                                                                    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>

Comment: setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product).'?show=1' ?>

Comment: Sorry but it not works the above code generate onclick="setLocation('http:....product/3/?show=1')". and there is no ?show=1 in url when we go to view.phtml So i can not use $_GET['show']

Comment: I am not able to send any argument from list.phtml to view.phtml.